# Socialite Laravel Facebook login

Tags: laravel

I got this error cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: graph.facebook.com  while trying laravel socialite for facebook login.I have been googling for about 4 hours and can't find a single solution and why it is happening. How to fix this error?

[image]

Comment: [It's always DNS](https://www.google.com/search?q=it's+always+dns)

Comment: what should i do ?